# Authentication Require Enter username and password to http://www

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, iis-7, windows-authentication, form-authentication

I am getting window authentication window popup on some of my views in mvc4. It works fine when I host it on local server. But when I upload my code to my hosting server, all the views works fine except some views.

I am using form authentication in my application. And the views which given me such popups their controller class define with `[Authorize]` attribute. Is it an issue with IIS on hosted server or something else?

This is the popup message:

[image: http://postimg.org/image/4slwg6ywx/]

Comment: what do you have `<authentication>` setup as in the web.config?

Comment: form authentication ;;after removing authorize attribute,it still not working :( ..i think some issue with iis

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that you have Integrated Windows Authentication or Basic Authentication configured in IIS for your website or application (depending on how you are hosting it). Make sure you disable it and enable anonymous access to the website if you want to use Forms Authentication.

1. Open IIS Manager and navigate to your website or application.
2. In Features View, double-click Authentication.
3. On the Authentication page, disable Windows authentication and enable Anonymous authentication.

Comment: @user2607683 ...How? This reply does not help anyone.

Comment: I have the same problem as the OP but the other way around.  It works fine on remote server but when running in IIS locally it throws up the authentication box.  My local IIS instance is already configured to use anonymous and forms ... all others are disabled.  Any ideas?

Comment: I think "Basic Auth" is similar. I'm mid-research, but I think all you want enabled is "Forms" and "Anonymous" authentication types. I was having the same issue, locally, and disabling "Basic Authentication" fixed it. I'm just double checking that is proper.